# Extracting numbers from weird version string

Tags: c++

I have a version number for an app that is the form 0x00870016 where the first 4 hexadecimal digits represent the first part of the version number and the second 4 the second part, so in this example the version number is 135.22.

I am trying to figure out how (in C++) I would extract these numbers separately to display them as a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using a combination of masks and shifts:

```
int main()
{
    const uint32_t v = 0x00870016;
    const uint16_t major = (v & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16; 
    const uint16_t minor = v & 0x0000FFFF;
    cout << major << "." << minor << "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
135.22
```

**Explanation:**

`0x00870016` is a 32-bit number.  Your major version number is composed from the 16 most-signifigant digits, and the minor version number is the 16 least-signifigant digits.

In order to extract the major version number, let's find out that the 16 MSBits are by masking the input value with `0xFFFF0000` -- a number where all 16 of the most-signifigant digits are set to `1` and all the least-sig bits are `0`:

```
0x00870016 && 0xFFFF0000 = 0x00870000
```

The resulting value is your major version number, shifted left 16 bits.  So lets shift it over:

```
0x00870000 >> 16 = 0x00000087
```

And there we have your real major version number.

Extracting the minor version number is similar, except we don't have to shift.

**Note:**

The first step could be simplified by skipping the mask:

```
const uint16_t major = v >> 16;
```

This works because the C++ Standard says that when you shift right, the vacated bits are populated with `0`s.  So the final program would be:

```
int main()
{
    const uint32_t v = 0x00870016;
    const uint16_t major = v >> 16;
    const uint16_t minor = v & 0x0000FFFF;
    cout << major << "." << minor << "\n";
}
```

**Edit:**

As noted in the comments, you might be getting `0x00870016` as a string, rather than a number.  We simply need to convert this string to it's numeric equivalent.  Dealing with the leading `0x` might seem like a stumbling block, but it's not if you use the C++ Standard Library iostream manipulators:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string inVer = "0x00870016";
    uint32_t v = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << inVer;
    ss >> std::hex >> v;
    const uint16_t major = v >> 16;
    const uint16_t minor = v & 0x0000FFFF;
    cout << major << "." << minor << "\n";
}
```

Comment: OP got the version as a string, I think it would be interesting to add the bit of code that converts it to an integral value at first for the sake of completeness

Comment: Don't use `uint32_t` and `uint16_t` here: they're overkill, because the **do not exist** on systems that don't have those exact sizes. If the code uses `uint_least32_t` or `uint_fast32_t` or `unsigned long` it will work just as well, and not have that portability hit.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  I can get behind that.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned version = 0x00870016;
unsigned major = version >> 16;
unsigned minor = version & 0xffff;

printf("Version %u.%u\n", major, minor);
```

or

```
std::cout << "Version " << major << "." << minor << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note that `unsigned` might not be large enough to hold `0x00870016`, since it is only required to hold values up to `0xffff`. Use `unsigned long` or, if you must (`<g>`), `uint_least32_t`.